# Tensorboard Event File Is Large and Growing

Tags: tensorflow

I am training a fairly complex network and noticed that the event file continues to grow during training and can reach a size of 2GB or more. I assume that the size of the event file should be approximately constant over a training session -- correct? I tried using tf.get_default_graph().finalize() placed just before the training loop per [mrry's suggestion](http://tf.get_default_graph().finalize()) but that did not cause any errors. How else can I go about debugging this?

Comment: TensorFlow appends to events file so it'll grow over time. You could save space by removing the most expensive summaries, like image_summary

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the events file was cumulative for non-scalar data. Is there a way to view  the (expensive) images from an earlier point in training?

Comment: not sure if there's an easy way. The hard way is to read the events file (it's TFRecords and there's a reader in TensorFlow codebase), figure out event protobuf message type, parse them as protobufs, and extract image summaries from the protobuf, and then visualize using PIL

Comment: Interesting. Might it be worthwhile to have some type of overwrite option for image_summary? It's very convenient to write and view images in TB, but I've noticed my training occasionally and mysteriously bogs down in the later stages and I'm beginning to suspect that it is related to the event file writing.

Comment: That might be tricky because TFRecords API only provides sequential access. One work-around is to restart your training job periodically, it's going to load from checkpoint and write to new events file